# Bokeh plot not updating after file (dataframe) change

Tags: python, visualization, bokeh

The accurate plot gets generated with *File1* being selected by default. When clicked on *File2* button, I can see in the console that the data from *df2* is getting into *source.data* but the plot doesn't update.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, ColorBar, HoverTool, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import RadioGroup
from bokeh.layouts import row

def main():
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'ABC1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'ABC2': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], 'score': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]})
    source1 = ColumnDataSource(df1)
    source = source1

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'ABC1': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], 'ABC2': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], 'score': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]})
    source2 = ColumnDataSource(df2)

    p = figure(title='ABC Visualization', x_axis_label='ABC1', y_axis_label='ABC2', toolbar_location='above')

    p.scatter("ABC1", "ABC2", source=source)

    hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Cell Name', '@index')], mode='mouse')

    p.add_tools(hover)

    radio_group = RadioGroup(labels=['File 1', 'File 2'], active=0)

    # Define the JavaScript callback function
    radio_callback = CustomJS(args=dict(radio_group=radio_group, source1=source1, source2=source2), code="""
        console.log('radio_group: active=' + this.active, this.toString())

        var source = this.active === 0 ? source1 : source2;
        console.log(source)

        source.change.emit()
    """)

    # Assign the callback 
    radio_group.js_on_change('active', radio_callback)

    layout = row([radio_group, p])

    show(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I am using Bokeh 3.1.1 and *python3 -m http.server* for visualization

Comment: Your callback is a no-op since you are naming a *local variable* source but not actually modifying the data source itself. You need to assign a new value to `source.data` where `source` is the CDS that is driving the scatter glyph. There are many examples of this pattern in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'ABC1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
        'ABC2': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], 
        'score': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]
    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ABC1': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], 
    'ABC2': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60], 
    'score': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]
})

source = ColumnDataSource(data=df1)
p = figure(title='ABC Visualization', x_axis_label='ABC1', y_axis_label='ABC2', toolbar_location='above')
p.scatter("ABC1", "ABC2", source=source)
hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Cell Name', '@index')], mode='mouse')
p.add_tools(hover)

radio_group = RadioGroup(labels=['File 1', 'File 2'], active=0)
radio_group.js_on_click(CustomJS(code="""
    console.log('radio_group: active=' + this.active, this.toString())
"""))

def update_source(file):
    df = df1 if file == 'File 1' else df2
    df_dict = df.to_dict("list")
    source.data = df_dict
    
def update(attr, old, new):
    index_active = radio_group.active
    file = radio_group.labels[index_active]
    update_source(file)

radio_group.on_change('active', update)
```